# Laravel 5.x and Node JS (Socket.IO)

Tags: node.js, laravel

Hi I'm having trouble with laravel 5 app and NodeJS (Socket.IO) I don't know why I am getting the 404 on my console in my listener link

I have my project running in localhost:8080 and I have 2 links:

1. For firing event
2. For writing

On my writing page I get an error (from my browser console) of:

GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LKBNQCv 404 (Not Found)

I have my socket.js that resides on my laravel app root folder:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {

});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
     console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);

     message = JSON.parse(message);

     io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
     console.log('Listening on Port 8080');
});
```

And my javascript on view (listener):

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/socket.io.js') }}"></script>

<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\NodeJSEvent", function(message){
     // increase the power everytime we load test route
     $('#power').text(parseInt($('#power').text()) + parseInt(message.data.power));
 });
</script>
```

Whenever I fire my other url (the one that triggers and adds the power) I receive this on my terminal:

```
{"event":"App\\Events\\NodeJSEvent","data":{"data":{"power":"10"},"socket":null}}
```

Thanks in advance for the kind help.

EDIT:

Ok thanks to Frank Provost for the comment and pointing out on where I was having a problem, I now changed my port on where my node server listens from port 8080 to 3000 (please do take note that my projects is running on http://localhost:8080), now my current problem is that I now get an error of:

```
socket.io.js:1456 GET localhost:3000/socket.io/… net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So where am I supposed to look now? Do I need to configure something/somewhere?

I'm using vagrant and Ubuntu 14.4 on my server and and apache2.

Thanks again in advance

Comment: is your node server up and running? try listening to another port - since your laravel app / apache server should already listen to 8080

Comment: Hi, I changed the port on my socket.js file from 8080 to 3000 but still get the same error.

Comment: you have to change it in both your node server and your client. Hopefully you've done so.

Comment: By client you mean the io('http://localhost:8080') part right? already changed to io('http://localhost:3000') but now I get 

socket.io.js:1456 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LKKgusE net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. Could you update your code of the question according to your current state?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I already solved my dilemma I tried adding these lines on my vagrant file:

```
#redis
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 6379, host: 6379

#node
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

and it works now thanks for the answer, suggestions and time to everyone who helped me.